# load on startup negative value in liberty

Tags: web.xml, websphere-liberty, negative-integer

I am currently migrating my application from WAS 8 to WAS Liberty, and I am stuck with the below problem. In one of my module web.xml file, the servlet load on startup value is -1. And the particular servlet is not getting invoked while running in Liberty. Can anyone help me with this? Please find the below code snippets from my web.xml,`<servlet>
        <servlet-name>SchedulerServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>SchedulerServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>com.metlife.bob.reassignment.scheduler.servlet.SchedulerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>`

Comment: What you mean 'not invoked'? -1 defines that servlet can be loaded when container needs it, so I'd assume it will be loaded during 1st request.

Answer (score 1):

Any negative value for load-on-startup means to defer loading the servlet until the first request is received, so unless something is invoking the servlet, it's not going to start on its own.  You can override this behavior in Liberty with the deferServletLoad attribute in server.xml as described in this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_servlet_load.html
As an aside, I noticed the name of your servlet includes "Scheduler" and you're migrating from traditional WebSphere to Liberty, I'm assuming you are aware that Liberty does not have a direct equivalent for traditional WebSphere scheduler service.

Comment: We added the below code <webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/> to the server.xml, but still the servlet is not getting invoked. We have the application configuration as <enterpriseApplication id="xyz" location="xyz.ear" name="xyz" type="ear"/>. Whether we need to provide the application as web application and then only web container will works?

Comment: Are you making any web request to the servlet?  Or are you expecting it to start in the absence of a web request?

Comment: It is a scheduler servlet which needs to be get started during the scheduled time. But it doesn't get started. We changed the load on startup to 0 and then only it started along with the server